# Android MpLine chart y axis on top some is invisible

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I'm using MpLine chart in my project. My problem is some times top part of y axis is not showing. In my xml I gave fixed height of 75dp to the graph. How can I make the graph to be shown within this height.Any help will appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(1000f); //to set max height place your value in place of 100f
leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f); // to set minimum yAxis place
```

Hope this helps! :)